# Lookahead in R issue

Tags: r, regex, string, extract, regex-lookarounds

I currently have a df in R with a column called FORMULAS that looks like this:

[image]

What I would like to do is to isolate the formula at the first equal sign:

[image]

This is the code I came up with so far:

```
df$FORMULAS <- str_extract(df$FORMULAS, "(?<=\\} =)")
```

where I have tried to use the lookahead procedure, but without much luck. 
Is this the best approach to solve the issue? Do you have any suggestions on what  am doing wrong?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: `df$FORMULAS <- str_extract(df$FORMULAS, "(?<==).+")`

Comment: I may be a simpleton, but I'd just `gsub("^[^=]*= ", "", df$FORMULAS)`

Answer (score 0):

So something like

```
trimws(sub(".*?=", "", x))
#[1] "a+b+c"       "a*b*c"       "a/b = c"     "bc + de = 1"
```

`?` lazily matches everything until first occurrence of `"="` and replaces it with empty string using `sub`.

where `x` is

```
x <- c("{X} = a+b+c", "{Y} = a*b*c", "{Z} = a/b = c", "a=bc + de = 1")
```

Added an extra input from @Wiktor's link.

Comment: Your regex [does not necessarily match](https://regex101.com/r/oJDAZW/1) the first `=`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok..so `\\s+` isn't necessary. `sub(".*?=", "", x)` works?